# NodeJS installation error on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, node.js

I'm trying to solve a problem with the Node js installation on an Oracle Linux server.

After I decompress a .tar file and try to install it, I get a syntax error. I would like to know if someone had similar problem and if they can tell me how can I can fix it.

Here is the syntax error:

```
$ ./configure
      File "./configure", line 511
        o['default_configuration'] = 'Debug' if options.debug else 'Release'
                                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a problem building Node.js from source on Oracle Linux.
However I mostly use the pre-built binaries from nodejs.org.
I also use the Oracle Linux Software Collections Library version of Node.js, see:
https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/entry/technology_preview_available_for_oracle 
and:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E59096/html/section_zlg_m3g_dq.html